# How to use weak and moderate in one sentence to explain the relationship

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

I have two variables. I examined the relationship between them I found that the association between them are weak to moderate I would like to describe this relationship in General. I do not need to explain them in specific.

I tried this, but feel my sentence is not correct or the structure is not good:

**The relationship between X and Y is almost negative (weak to moderate)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word that comes to mind, since you use the word “negative”, and also suggest that the relationship isn’t worthy of explanation, is:

> **Negligible**: *so small or unimportant as to be not worth considering; insignificant.*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are doing exactly, but normally the word "correlation" is used to describe how two variables are related to each other.

If you say they are negatively correlated, this means that as one increases the other decreases, so this is probably not what you mean.

You can say the correlation is "weak" or "moderate". For something in between, you could use "moderately weak"!